# Better way of writing my SQL query with conditional group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Here's my data

```
|vendorname |total|
---------------------
|Najla      |10   |
|Disney     |20   |
|Disney     |10   |
|ToysRus    |5    |
|ToysRus    |1    |
|Gap        |1    |
|Gap        |2    |
|Gap        |3    |
|Najla      |2    |
```

Here's the resultset I want

```
|vendorname |grandtotal|
---------------------
|Disney     |30   |
|Gap        |6    |
|ToysRus    |6    |
|Najla      |2    |
|Najla      |10   |
```

If the vendorname = 'Najla' I want individual rows with their respective total otherwise I would like to group them and return a sum of their totals.

This is my query--

```
select * 
from
(
    select vendorname, sum(total) grandtotal
    from vendor
    where vendorname<>'Najla'
    group by vendorname 

    union all

    select vendorname, total grandtotal
    from vendor
    where vendorname='Najla'
) A
```

I was wondering if there's a better way to write this query instead of repeating it twice and performing a union. Is there a condensed way to group some rows "conditionally".

Comment: First, you should probably use `union all` instead of `union` there. `union` without `all` will remove duplicates, which would be bad if you had two rows where 'Najla' had the same `total`.

Comment: Good point! Thanks.

Comment: Second, if you have an index on column `vendorname` (preferently `vendorID`) you won't read table twice, just once

Comment: Your method (with `union all`) is probably the best method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Honestly, I think the `union all` version is going to be the best performing and easiest to read option if it has appropriate indexes.

You could, however, do something like this (assuming you have a unique `id` on your table):

```
select vendorname, sum(total) grandtotal
from t
group by 
    vendorname
  , case when vendorname = 'Najla' then id else null end
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/OGZQ33364

returns

```
+------------+------------+
| vendorname | grandtotal |
+------------+------------+
| Disney     |         30 |
| Gap        |          6 |
| ToysRus    |          6 |
| Najla      |         10 |
| Najla      |          2 |
+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful.